# Как получить доступ к членам компонента загруженного из другого fxml-файла?

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть 3 fxml-файла - основное окно приложения, панель навигации, и панель контента.
При помощи fxml-импорта я смог собрать из этого целостный интерфейс, но теперь появляется закономерный вопрос - как уведомлять другие окна о событиях друг-друга?
Например, когда я загружаю файл в главном окне, мне нужно передать полученные данные в панель контента и панель навигации, а я даже не могу сообщить им аргументы! (нужно как-то воспользоваться `@FXML initialize()`?)
p.s. я воспользовался паттерном Наблюдатель, но потом подумал, что это не должно быть так сложно - с чего бы такая типовая задача требовала громоздкой мишуры из вспомогательных классов?..

Comment: Суть в том, что все окна должны ссылаться на один компонент, модель. То есть, я загружаю файл в модель, которую слушают все необходимоые окна и когда файл загружен, нужные окна соответсвующе на это реагируют

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko хмм... тобишь, всё-таки, обзервер - вполне стандартное решение для такой ситуации?

Comment: Осбоенно учитывая, что весь функционал реализован при помощи javafx properties. Гуглите и учите как использовать

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko хорошо, спасибо, направление интересное